# kdevelop4 and C++ requires cmake

Tags: cmake, kdevelop

I want to use kdevelop4 for c++ programming but when I try to run the application kdevelop4 wants cmake binary file! How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you need to install CMake.  If you are on a Linux system, `aptitude install cmake` (for Debian/ubuntu) or `yum install cmake` (for Red Hat/Fedora) should do the trick.  On Windows, you may need to [download and install](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html) CMake yourself.